# String index in Swift 2.0: How can I work around indexing a string?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to get the contents of a string:

```
var oldString = "hi this \t is my \t string"
oldString = String(oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t"))
print(oldString[1])
```

> I get the ERROR : " 'subscript' is unavailable:cannot subscript String
>   with an Int..."

How would I access a string that is contained in another string? 
The only way I have come up with is to get character by character using:

```
for index in content.characters.indices{
    print(String(oldString[index]))
}
```

The code above results in:

```
h,
i,
t,
h,
..
```

I need:

```
hi this,
is my,
string
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**You should read the error message and figure out where does the error message come from.**

Your `String(oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t"))` gives you a `String` not `[String]`.

What you need to do is assigning `oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")` to an array:

```
let stringArray = oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")
for str in stringArray {
  print(str)
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. How would I make it a [String]?

Comment: `oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")` returns a `[String]`. You are taking the result of that and making a new String from it, which is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In swift you can extend any type and add overloads for different operations. In the example below we've created an extension that allows you to subscript `String` returning each word and get an array from your string.

Simply paste this into a playground to test:

```
extension String {
    
    func array() -> [String] {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")
    }
    
    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")[i]
    }
}
```

Once you've added your extension, you can use it throughout your application like so:

```
var str = "hi this \t is my \t string"

print(str[0]) //prints hi this

for i in str.array() {
    print(i)
}
```

prints:

> hi this
>
> is my
>
> string

Answer (score 0):

```
    var oldString = "hi this \t is my \t string"
    let stringArray = oldString.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")

    //In case you also need the index while iterating
    for (index, value) in stringArray.enumerate(){
        print("index is \(index) and string is \(value)")
    }

    for str in stringArray{
        print(str)
    }

Output will be as follows
index is 0 and string is hi this 
index is 1 and string is  is my 
index is 2 and string is  string

hi this 
 is my 
 string
```